# PL/SQL Regular expression not working

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have the following code:

```
declare
  l_input      clob;
  l_output     clob;
  function check_this_regex(
    io_str    in out clob
    ,o_found  out clob
  ) return boolean
  is
    l_match   clob;
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Matching against ->' || io_str || '<-');
    l_match := regexp_substr(io_str, '"((y)*)"');

    if l_match is null then
      return false;
    end if;

    o_found := l_match;
    return true;
  end;
begin
  l_input := to_clob('x');
  dbms_output.put_line('l_input->' || l_input || '<-');
  if (check_this_regex(l_input, l_output)) then
     dbms_output.put_line('Found: ' || l_output);
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('Not found');
  end if;
end;
```

Why does this output `Found`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be checking a clob against `NULL`; editing your check this way

```
if l_match /* is null */ = empty_clob() then
```

gives :

```
l_input->x<-
Matching against ->x<-
Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

regexp_substr for clob alwas returns not null value.Check example.

```
declare 
 v_clob clob;
 v_in clob :='a';

 v_str varchar2(10);
 v_st_in  varchar2(10) :='a';
begin 
 v_clob := regexp_substr(v_in,'xx');
 if v_clob is null then
  dbms_output.put_line('aaa');
 end if;
 v_str := regexp_substr(v_st_in,'xx');
 if v_str is null then
  dbms_output.put_line('aaa');
 end if;
end;
```